# How to beat Matriarch Benezia with little health?

Tags: mass-effect

I am playing as an infiltrator and I've just beaten the first wave of commandos Benezia sends after you in Mass Effect. The game automatically saved and after the conversation ends and I am meant to kill her, I have little health, no medpacks and my team also has little health.

My team consists of Ashley and Benezia's daughter (whose name I forget), one of which gets put in stasis mode every single time.

There doesn't seem to be anywhere I can run to seek cover.

The closest I came was using the marksman ability and telling my team-members to attack Benezia and getting her down to a sliver of health before a commando killed me.

Suggestions?

Comment: What class are you using? That might help people get a better idea of your situation.

Comment: @Kotsu I'm playing as infiltrator, edited question to reflect.

Comment: Stay at the door, barricade yourself there and make sure Benezia does not have line of sight to you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had this problem when running through on Insanity.  I ended up doing the following after many, many tries.

I ran away from Benezia, back toward where you come into the room.  I also made sure that my squad was following me.  There were some commandos there, and took them out using powers and the squads guns, and then made the left to that platform.

From there, I personally used my best long-ranged weapon and took out all enemies that could see me from there.  Benezia was not one of them.    Once I slowly and carefully picked off all enemies, allowing armor to regenerate between each, I then had my entire squad attack Benezia.

I also had the Unity power for all of this, but I don't think I used it at all during this battle once I figured out this tactic.

I think that the best thing you can do is try something other than take her on right away.  Bide your time and take care of minions first.  Use talents liberally (Shield Boost, etc.)

Comment: Alas I tried that, but there are commandos from where I entered the room, and when I hide behind a crate before going there they come and shoot me.... Are there any medpacks in the room?

Comment: When I played as infiltrator, I was lucky - both Benezia and the commando spawn door were on the opposite side of the room, hidden by the zergling tank. I slowly worked my way forward, sniping commandos as they appeared, until the room was clear, then focused on Benezia.

Comment: @Rhino.  That is what I experienced as well.  m3tron0me - You don't hide between those crates for long.  Pop out, hit one of them coming to you, and back in.  Even if it doesn't kill them, they will stop for a little bit.  Use cover, use abilities, and use your ability to recharge shields.  I don't think there are medpacks in the room.  Even with this tactic, I remember doing this a few times before getting it, but each time I got a little farther and realized I was at least going in the right direction.

Comment: Just went back and played this part again (luckily had a save fairly shortly before).  On first attempt, went right, and killed all enemies before Benezia killed me.  Reload, went other direction and killed everybody.  I lost T'Soni due to the stasis, but Kaiden was with me.  He went down too, but I was able to take out last commando on my own.  Did not use any talents, medpacs, etc.  Just my best gun and keeping moving.  If that does not work for you, then reload the closest save before this, and save right outside the door before trying.  There is a lot of medigel in the area I noticed.

Answer (score 1):

Use Sabotage, followed by Overload and then attack her with your best pistol while using Marksman.

Answer (score 0):

When I played the mission to kill the Matriarch, I was an Infiltrator and used the pistol and assault rifle.  The Matriarch had very low health, but so did I.  One of my teammates died and Ashley killed two commandos.  The Matriarch went to get Ashley, so I sneaked up behind the Matriarch and shot her in the head over and over again with the pistol.  As soon as it overheated, she was on the ground.

So my strategy would be to use one of your teammates as bait, and sneak up on the Matriarch and blow her head off.  But make sure she has low health.  As for the commandos, I was just lucky Ashley was there.

Answer (score -1):

I just did a playthrough.
I played as a Vanguard and broke it up into waves. I had Tali and Garrus with me. Garrus kept dying on me, but Tali was very helpful with her Sabotage and Overload. She, along with my Carnage against the commandos, as well as Hacking against the Geth that attack you, and finally, when I got rid of the Geth and commandos, I used a combo of Overload, Damping, Carnage, Adrenaline Rush, and Assassination a few times, and she was dead.